# MongoDB/Mongoose Cannot find documents by querying property

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a MongoDB set up on a remote host and developing an application on localhost. I use Node.js and Express for server and Mongoose (v.5.0.11) for connecting to the MongoDB. I have the following structure of DB entity "Visit" described:

```
var Visits = new Schema({
  client: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client',
    required: true,
  },
  sources: Object,
  landingReached: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: new Date(),
  },
  trackLink: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'TrackLink',
    required: true,
  },
  offer: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Offer',
    required: true,
  },
  geoRef: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Geo',
  },
  finalURL: String,
  domain: String,
  prelandURL: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: '',
  },
})
Visits.plugin(idvalidator)
var VisitsModel = mongoose.model('Visits', Visits)
module.exports.Visits = VisitsModel
```

I want to query all visits by offers. E.g. if offers=[10,17], but here comes the error. I've tried to get at least one Visit with offer = 17. They are certainly in the DB, because I can query them in MongoDB on the target server:

```
> db.visits.find({offer:17}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad88c6cd3ac832134dd55c9"), "landingReached" : true, "date" : ISODate("2018-04-19T12:32:44.418Z"), "prelandURL" : "", "client" : ObjectId("5ad88c6cd3ac832134dd55c8"), "trackLink" : "65", "sources" : { }, "offer" : 17, "geoRef" : ObjectId("5ab50cf7a7999b1a5836fcf2"), "finalURL" : "", "domain" : "", "__v" : 0 }
```

But using Mongoose code I cannot find it:

```
 schemas.Visits.find({offer: 17}).
      limit(1).
      exec((err, vis) => {
        console.info(err, vis)
      })
    schemas.Visits.find({offer: '17'}).
      limit(1).
      exec((err, vis) => {
        console.info(err, vis)
      })
```

Both variants result in "null []" response in logs

However, if I query using trackLink property - everything is ok:

```
schemas.Visits.find({trackLink: 65}).
      limit(1).
      exec((err, vis) => {
        console.info(err, vis)
      })
```

This returns the same value as MongoDB.

I have no idea why it's working so. I've tried to pass offerId differently (as String, as Number, and as ObjectId even). I've tried to query Offer first and then use it's _id property to query Visits. Also checked that schemas file is correct and MongoDB URL and authentication data is correct. I would appreciate any ideas.

Note: there are almost 16000 entries in Visits table, but I don't think that this is an issue.

Comment: Schema is wrong. Should be `Number` as in `offer: { type: Number, ref: 'Offer',  required: true }`. Mongoose is converting whatever you type in to a "string" and that is not going to match the data in the collection which is numeric.

Comment: @NeilLunn Ok, but why for trackLink it works? I can get the same Visit querying by trackLink:65 and trackLink:'65'

Comment: @NeilLunn Oh, ok, you're right! I store offer property as a numeric value in DB. This is the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Becuase it's actually "stored" as a string. You can't just interchangeably use one or the other. It's called "casting", so when the "schema type" says "String" then that's what mongoose tries to send the query as.